# Decay of the Meson

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, quarks, mesons

I'm trying to draw Feynman diagrams for 'The decay of the pseudoscalar meson $\phi = |s \bar{s}\rangle $ into these final states:

i) $\phi \rightarrow \pi^{+} \pi^{-},$ where $\pi^{+}=|u \bar{d}\rangle$ and $\pi^{-}=|d \bar{u}\rangle$

ii) $\phi \rightarrow \pi^{+} \pi^{-} \gamma$
'

but when I was reading up how to do them, I came across this from David Griffin's 'Introduction to Elementary Particles' which seems to explicitily say that the reaction isn't possible. This tarries with everything else I've found on the web: the ϕ doesn't decay into just two two pions. Is there an error in the question ? If not, how I can go about attacking how to draw the Feynman diagrams ?
[image: Taken from Page 75, David Griffins]

Comment: Greetings! Your shortened version of the question invalidated the existing answer, so I have restored it.

Answer (score 2):

A quick trip to the PDG will reassure you that reaction i) goes at a BR of $7\cdot  10^{-5}$ and reaction ii) at $4\cdot 10^{-5}$.

What Griffiths' book calls "forbidden" means "greatly suppressed", and I assume you went where he is sending you — but I am not familiar with that text.

In the strong interactions, I and G are pretty good symmetries, so the φ having negative G cannot go *strongly* to two pions each with G=-, so collectively with G=+.

Nevertheless, electromagnetism breaks I and hence G, and an exchanged photon costs an  *α* in the amplitude and the square of that in the rate. Do you *now* see where the suppression factor in the BR must be coming from? What do your Feynman diagrams look like?

Comment: Thanks-  that's reassuring ! I've added what I think the Feynman diagram is, but I'm still  not sure where the photon is radiated from.

Comment: From any quark; for i), from any quark to any other, more or less.

Comment: Thank-You, does the Feynman diagram look correct to you?  Thank-You so much!

Comment: Doesn’t look wrong, only funny: The photon could originate in the middle of a quark line.